# How to generate session id and authorization tokens for linked service programatically?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a linked service that requires authorization and session id. The objective is to create ADF project in local and push the same to Azure via VSTS CI/CD pipeline. Whenever I deploy the project using powershell script, I get authorization issue. How do I handle this? I noticed a C# script in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-usql-activity. But how do I integrated this with my ADF project? Any suggestions (preferably in step by step format) will be of help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share the error messages about authorization issue here?

Comment: I get this error message when I try to deploy the linkedservice- New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService : Credential operation error: The authorization code for your  linked service is
invalid to generate authentication token. Please reauthorize this linked service with an account that has access to your resource and promptly redeploy the linkedservice

Comment: Which build task do you use for the deployment?

Comment: Azure powershell task

Answer (score 0):

You can now use service principals with Azure Data Lake so no need to generate session and tokens for the linked service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-authenticate-using-active-directory

Hope this helps

Comment: Judging by the link in the question, I bet they were having trouble with Data Lake Analytics (rather than store). But good news, that has also just added service principal support. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-usql-activity#service-principal-authentication-recommended